# Delete and Merge Records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as following.

```
id | firstname|  lastname |  email       |   homephone
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | aaa      | bbb       | xxx@yyy.com  |  12344444    
2  | aaa      | bbb       | null         |  null    
3  | ccc      | ddd       | zzz@fff.com  | null  
4  | ccc      | ddd       | null         | 34343322
```

The issue is I want to keep only 1 record since these are considered as duplicates and merge the nulls so that the table appears as follows

```
1 aaa | bbb | xxx@yyy.com | 12344444  
3 ccc | ddd | zzz@fff.com | 3433322
```

So far I have managed to get the duplicates using the following the code

```
Select 
   max(a.id) as original id, b.id as DuplicateId, 
   a.firstname, b.firstname as dup_fname,
   a.lastname, b.lastname as dup_lname,
   a.email, b.email 
From 
   tbl_xxx a 
join 
   tbl_xxx b on a.firstname = b.firstname
             and a.lastname = b.lastname
             and a.email is null
             and a.homephone is null
             and b.email is null
             and b.homephone is null
             and v.id < v2.id   
Group by 
   b.id, a.firstname, b.firstname, a.lastname,
   b.lastname, a.homephone, b.homephone
```

My merge query looks like this

```
update tbl_xxx 
SET
    email = email , 
    phone = phone  
where 
    firstname = firstname
    and lastname = lastname 
    and email is null 
    and phone is null
```

Eventually I will get distinct rows.

Is my approach correct? kindly suggest how can I make my query more efficient

Comment: do you want to update your table are you like to select the rows with out null value

Comment: Preferably I want to update the table without any duplicates

Comment: Shouldn't one of the table references in the first query be looking for rows _with_ values?  If you have anything pointing to the ids being removed, you need to point them to the condensed row.  Also, names aren't unique, are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Yup the information has already been filtered previously so I can based myself on lastname and firstname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update tbl_tmpdupes3 SET
email = email , 
phone = phone , 
where 
firstname=firstname
and lastname=lastname 
and email is null 
and homephone is null
```

will do absolutely nothing, since the query is not comparing the table against itself, but each row against itself. Using an update won't work either, you'll still have duplicates. What you want is to remove the duplicate data entirely, AFTER doing an update comparing the table to itself. So, basically we run one query that ensures all information in duplicates that is not null is copied to the originals, then we delete the higher value pk.

One way of tackling the problem update one column at a time:

```
update tbl_xxx SET tbl_xxx.email = tmp.email 
FROM (SELECT tbl_xxx.firstname,tbl_xxx.lastname,tbl_xxx.email FROM tbl_xxx
     WHERE NOT tbl_xxx.email IS NULL LIMIT 1) 
AS tmp ON tmp.firstname = tbl_xxx.firstname AND tmp.lastname = tbl_xxx.lastname
WHERE tbl_xxx.email IS NULL;

update tbl_xxx SET tbl_xxx.phone = tmp.phone 
FROM (SELECT tbl_xxx.firstname,tbl_xxx.lastname,tbl_xxx.phone FROM tbl_xxx
     WHERE NOT tbl_xxx.phone IS NULL LIMIT 1) 
AS tmp ON tmp.firstname = tbl_xxx.firstname AND tmp.lastname = tbl_xxx.lastname
WHERE tbl_xxx.phone is NULL;
```

The query finds the values of each column for first name and last name, and copies over first value it finds into null fields. So, if the original data was missing, it will add it. It may not be 100% correct if two different people in the DB have the same name, you'll have to take that into consideration.

That said, follow it up with this query, which should only delete the higher-pk row that is identical.

```
DELETE FROM tbl_xxx WHERE tbl_xxx.id IN (
    SELECT max(id) FROM tbl_xxx 
    GROUP BY tbl_xxx.firstname,tbl_xxx.lastname,tbl_xxx.phone,tbl_xxx.email
    HAVING count(tbl_xxx.id) > 1));
```

Edit: if there are potentially multiple duplicates, you could do:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_xxx WHERE tbl_xxx.id NOT IN (
    SELECT min(id) FROM tbl_xxx
    GROUP BY tbl_xxx.firstname,tbl_xxx.lastname,tbl_xxx.phone,tbl_xxx.email);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot serakfalcon, I applied your logic and problem solved, really saved me from hours of pain. :)

Comment: just one update on the query I used the following 
update tbl_tmpdupes3 SET tbl_tmpdupes3.homephone = tmp.homephone 
FROM (SELECT tbl_tmpdupes3.firstname,tbl_tmpdupes3.lastname,tbl_tmpdupes3.homephone FROM tbl_tmpdupes3
     WHERE NOT tbl_tmpdupes3.homephone IS NULL) AS tmp 
where tmp.firstname = tbl_tmpdupes3.firstname AND tmp.lastname = tbl_tmpdupes3.lastname
and tbl_tmpdupes3.homephone IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement for this. Try this sample.

```
create table temptable (id int, firstname varchar(50),  lastname varchar(50),  email       varchar(50),   homephone varchar(50))

insert into temptable values
(1,'aaa' , 'bbb', 'xxx@yyy.com', 1234444),
(2,'aaa' , 'bbb', null, null),
(3,'ccc' , 'ddd', 'abc@ddey.com', null),
(4,'ccc' , 'ddd', null, 34343322  )

select * from temptable

;with cte as
(
    select firstname, lastname
    ,(select top 1 id from temptable b where b.firstname = a.firstname and b.lastname = a.lastname and ( b.email is not null or b.homephone is not null)) tid
    ,(select top 1 email from temptable b where b.firstname = a.firstname and b.lastname = a.lastname and b.email is not null )  email
    ,(select top 1 homephone from temptable b where b.firstname = a.firstname and b.lastname = a.lastname and b.homephone is not null ) homephone
    from temptable a
    group by firstname , lastname
)

--select * from cte
merge temptable as a
using cte as b
on ( a.id = b.tid )
when matched 
    then 
    update set a.email = b.email , a.homephone = b.homephone    
when not matched by source then
    delete ;

select * from temptable

drop table temptable
```